# How do I use groupby and mean in a sprase matrix?

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, mean

everyone, I have a question that puzzled me. Hope you can help me. Thank you in advanced.

I have a sparse matrix ,it looks like this .

```
    (2, 0)  1.3862943611198906
   (7, 0)   1.0986122886681096
  (27, 0)   1.0986122886681096
  (29, 0)   1.0986122886681096
  (31, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (37, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (41, 0)   3.1780538303479458
  (42, 0)   1.0986122886681096
  (45, 0)   1.3862943611198906
  (47, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (51, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (52, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (55, 0)   1.0986122886681096
  (56, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (60, 0)   2.0794415416798357
  (62, 0)   2.639057329615259
  (64, 0)   2.0794415416798357
  (65, 0)   2.3978952727983707
  (66, 0)   1.3862943611198906
  (69, 0)   1.0986122886681096
  (70, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (72, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (73, 0)   1.6094379124341003
  (77, 0)   0.6931471805599453
  (78, 0)   1.3862943611198906
  : :
  (19669, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19670, 65535)    1.0986122886681096
  (19671, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19675, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19677, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19678, 65535)    1.0986122886681096
  (19686, 65535)    1.3862943611198906
  (19687, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19688, 65535)    2.0794415416798357
  (19689, 65535)    1.6094379124341003
  (19690, 65535)    2.1972245773362196
  (19691, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19692, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19693, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19694, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19695, 65535)    2.5649493574615367
  (19696, 65535)    2.639057329615259
  (19697, 65535)    0.6931471805599453
  (19698, 65535)    2.3978952727983707
  (19699, 65535)    1.6094379124341003
  (19700, 65535)    1.791759469228055
  (19701, 65535)    1.791759469228055
  (19702, 65535)    1.0986122886681096
  (19703, 65535)    1.6094379124341003
  (19704, 65535)    3.5263605246161616
(19706, 65536)
```

Now, I have another columns and I called it as "A" it looks like this.

```
                gene_id
0      ENSMUSG00000031144
1      ENSMUSG00000031144
2      ENSMUSG00000031144
3      ENSMUSG00000031144
4      ENSMUSG00000031144
5      ENSMUSG00000031144
6      ENSMUSG00000031155
7      ENSMUSG00000031155
8      ENSMUSG00000031155
9      ENSMUSG00000031155
10     ENSMUSG00000031155
11     ENSMUSG00000031161
12     ENSMUSG00000031161
13     ENSMUSG00000031161
14     ENSMUSG00000031161
15     ENSMUSG00000031161
16     ENSMUSG00000031161
17     ENSMUSG00000031161
18     ENSMUSG00000031161
19     ENSMUSG00000031161
20     ENSMUSG00000031161
21     ENSMUSG00000031161
22     ENSMUSG00000031161
23     ENSMUSG00000031161
24     ENSMUSG00000031161
25     ENSMUSG00000031161
26     ENSMUSG00000031161
27     ENSMUSG00000031161
28     ENSMUSG00000031161
29     ENSMUSG00000031161
...                   ...
19676  ENSMUSG00000042532
19677  ENSMUSG00000042532
19678  ENSMUSG00000042532
19679  ENSMUSG00000042532
19680  ENSMUSG00000042532
19681  ENSMUSG00000025196
19682  ENSMUSG00000025196
19683  ENSMUSG00000025196
19684  ENSMUSG00000025196
19685  ENSMUSG00000025196
19686  ENSMUSG00000025196
19687  ENSMUSG00000025036
19688  ENSMUSG00000025025
19689  ENSMUSG00000025025
19690  ENSMUSG00000025025
19691  ENSMUSG00000025025
19692  ENSMUSG00000025025
19693  ENSMUSG00000025025
19694  ENSMUSG00000025025
19695  ENSMUSG00000024985
19696  ENSMUSG00000024985
19697  ENSMUSG00000024985
19698  ENSMUSG00000024985
19699  ENSMUSG00000024985
19700  ENSMUSG00000024985
19701  ENSMUSG00000024985
19702  ENSMUSG00000025075
19703  ENSMUSG00000025089
19704  ENSMUSG00000025089
19705  ENSMUSG00000025089

[19706 rows x 1 columns]
```

They have the same rows. I want to groupby the "A" and then get the mean values of this sparse matrix every columns. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What language and modules are you using?  Those are more useful tags than ones like `matrix` and `mean`.

Comment: I am using python